# Documentation review : Providing feedback

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

I did not find option to add comment on code examples documented by other user.

In this post :

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/design-patterns/1331/strategy-pattern

Everything is lifted from below web page.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm

How to send feedback to author of post to update with his own example Or use limited content from external site?

Comment: As far as I know, you can flag a topic or example, using the handy flag feature at the top right.

Answer (score 2):

Use request improvement flag 
[image: Use request improvement flag]

And select option which is more suitable for your case
[image]
Probably unclear, and write detailed description related to the issue.